# Pass api/json data from one component to another component on ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 component
Leftbar and Rightbar.
In the Leftbar component i have to fetch some json data from api when the input is filled and submitted and i have to pass the data to the Rightbar component. I dont know how to use props in this condition

```
<div className="App">
    <div className="main">
       <LeftBar/> //this component have fetched the json data 
       <RightBar/> //this component need to get the data 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have to show us some code, and are there child/parents components ?

Comment: @Versifiction Just posted the code . No , there is no child/parent component

Comment: you either need to use a library like Redux to manage your datas globally in your app, or to fetch at the App level to send datas to the 2 child components

Comment: In your app.jsx, create a state variable using useState, and pass state variable to both the components as props, also whenever data  is fetched in 1st component, update this state using callback function in app.jsx. This way you will get updated data in your second component as well.

Comment: @Versifiction Fetching at the App level works but i have to give input to fetch the data which is on one of the component .so, basically i need manage data globally so, I will look more on Redux library . Thanks for the suggestion :)